# Pavement Stencils - 1/16" (63 mil) or 1/8" (128 mil)?

Tags: paint, paving

We plan to ask a painter to paint parking space numbers in the parking lot (12" x 9").

There is on Amazon a kit for pavement stencils that has good reviews - is there a reason to prefer the 1/4" size (which is more expensive)?

Thank you.

Comment: If your contractor specializes in painting pavement, I'd expect him to have her own set of stencils for numbering and lettering just about everything including handicap spots.

Comment: Since this is a DIY site... have you considered doing it yourself?  you'd save a few bucks..

Comment: It's a private parking space of a condominium. No need for handicap spots as all spots are deeded and owned individually.

Comment: I can do it myself, but there are going to be other challenges that require communication from the management regarding to ask cars to stay away of the parking lot (so painting is just part of the task). What would be a suitable paint for that (any outdoors yellow?). Also - how soon after painting is it possible to drive on the painted numbers?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest asking your painter. They might have a preference, and you might save money overall by following their preference, if they have one. Cheap materials that waste paid professionals time can be VERY expensive...or they might already own a set of number stencils, or know where to borrow/rent a set inexpensively.

Depending on materials, the thicker ones might stay put better and save you money overall if the painter does not have to spend lots of time fussing with a thin stencil that does not want to stay put, blows in the wind, etc.

This is more likely if it's a flexible/rubbery/plastic material.

Then again, it might just be a durability issue (how many uses you'd expect to get from them) and make no difference for limited use.

This is more likely for a stiff/rigid stencil material.